# Pass ID from Foreach to Html.BeginForm

Tags: javascript, c#, html, model-view-controller

I need and Id `@item.errorId` from my model that I loop `foreach` to be passed when submitting the form, as the submitted form will have to be tracked back to exact row.

I attempt to create a single page application.

This is my CSHTML to create a table

```
   <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model.LogItems)
            {
                <tr href="#/" onclick="createTicket('@HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(item.Type)', '@HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(item.TimeUtc.ToString())', '@HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(item.Host)', '@HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(item.Message)', '@HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(item.Source)', '@HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(item.User)', '@HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(item.AllXml)', '@HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(item.ErrorId.ToString())')" style="cursor: pointer">
                    <td scope="row"> @(rowNo += 1) </td>
                    <td style="white-space: nowrap;">
                        @item.TimeUtc
                    </td>
                    <td style="word-wrap:break-word; max-width: 250px;">
                        @item.Type
                    </td>
                    <td>@item.Host</td>
                    <td style="max-width: 200px; word-wrap:break-word;"> @item.Message</td>
                    <td>
                        @item.Source
                    </td>
                    @if (item.User != "")
                    {
                        <td>@item.User</td>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <td><i>null</i></td>
                    }
                    <td>@item.AllXml.Split('"')[1].Split('"')[0]...</td>
                    <td style="white-space: nowrap;"> <button class="btn btn-link btn-xs">Dismiss</button></td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
```

Javascript handles the onClick that will pass values to `innerHtml` and display the "window"

```
  function createTicket(type, time, host, message, source, user, xml, errorid) {        

        if (ticketSwitch == true) {
                popup.style.visibility = "visible";
                cardHeader.innerHTML = type;
                timeForLogs.innerHTML = time;
                cardHost.innerHTML = host;
                cardMessage.innerHTML = message;
                cardSource.innerHTML = source;
                cardUser.innerHTML = user;
                cardText.innerText = xml;
                id.innerHTML = errorid;
                ticketSwitch = false;
            }
}
```

after clicking on the row, we get this

[image: after clicking on the row, we get this]

we can click a TICKET tab

[image]

this is CSHTML BeginForm

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Ticket", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                <div>
                    <br />
                    <div style="background-color:#2C3E5070; color: white; padding: 3px; border-radius:3px; font-weight: 300;">
                        <a style="font-size: 0.9em">Create Issue</a>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <form>
                        <span style="font-size: 0.8em">Project<sup class="star">*</sup></span> @Html.DropDownListFor(m => model.fields.project.key, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Projects, "<select>", new { @class = "form-control input-sm my-size-text-area input-background" })
                        <br />
                        <span style="font-size: 0.8em">Issue type</span> @Html.DropDownListFor(m => model.fields.issuetype.name, new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem { Text = "Bug", Value = "Bug" }, new SelectListItem { Text = "Feature", Value = "Feature" }, new SelectListItem { Text = "Task", Value = "Task" }, }, new { @class = "form-control input-sm my-size-text-area input-background" })
                        <br />
                        <span style="font-size: 0.8em">Assignee<sup class="star">*</sup></span> @Html.DropDownListFor(m => model.fields.assignee.name, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Users, "<select>", new { @class = "form-control input-sm my-size-text-area input-background" })
                        <br />
                        <span style="font-size: 0.8em">Summary<sup class="star">*</sup></span>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => model.fields.summary, new { @class = "form-control input-sm my-size-text-area input-background" })
                        <br />
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <span style="font-size: 0.8em">Description<sup class="star">*</sup></span> @Html.TextAreaFor(m => model.fields.description, 5, 60, new { @class = "form-control my-size-text-area input-background" })
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <input style="font-size: 0.8em !important;" onclick="loadingOverlay()" id="Submit" class="btn btn-primary float-right" type="submit" value="Create" />
                    </form>
                </div>
            }
```

on submitting the ticket I would like to pass Id that I can get from `foreach` into the Controller that handles My POST request.

Closest I got to do that was passing it as a value within

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Ticket", FormMethod.Post))
```

but that will always pass id from the last `foreach` item.

I appreciate all the help

Comment: Please clarify exactly what you are asking.

Comment: I have edited the post and clarified as much as i could. thank you

Comment: Try click event on a row with the class name, declare there your own attributes and access them all in javascript using 'this' keyword. This may be to solve your problem.

Comment: this will return a an empty log 

`   jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $(".rowId").click(function () {
                var id = $(this).val();
                console.log(id)
    });
});`

but I can log just `this` and it will return a whole element and inside there we get value="<some-id>", but I don't know how to acces it

Comment: You will nothing like this. Pass you errorid in custome\ attribute and then access it like `<tr data-id="{errorid}" ...</tr>` and in click event `$(this).data("id")`.

Comment: that worked great! now I need to find a way to pass that somwhere within BeginForm

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

1. Assign errorid to a hidden field in  `cshtml`

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => m.errorId)
```

2. Access the hidden field value in your controller.

Comment: I have corrected my post to clarify that ID is not a row number in this case but  `@item.errorId` and if I try to pass it like this `onclick="createTicket('@HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(item.errorId)',......"` it will always be a last id of the table

Comment: OK... Then you can try adding a hidden field in `cshtml`... Hidden field will be sent as part of the form to controller